# module.exports and ... what does it refer to

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've came across the following code block inside a Node.js / React app yet I am not sure what does the three dots ( ... ) refer to? I tried searching the web but couldn't find any information, so will appreciate any help on clarifying what they are exactly? Thanks

```
import item from './item';
import user from './user';
import warehouses from './warehouses';

module.exports = {
  ...item,
  ...user,
  ...warehouses,
};
```

Comment: [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three dots is called the "spread operator". It performs the same function as `Object.assign()`. It lets you copy the properties from one object to another object.

For example:

```
const a = {a: 1};
const b = {b: 2};
const c = {...a, ...b}; // c === {a: 1, b: 2}
```

For more reference: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html